# Tests are passing, coverage is not showing

Tags: babeljs, istanbul, ava, nyc

I'm trying to get `nyc` `ava` and `babel` to all place nice together. I was having an issue where async / await branches were showing as not covered, so this was working, I'm having trouble integrating the `babel-plugin-istanbul` plugin for tests.

I have two files in the project, `src/index.js` and `src/test.js`.

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "ava",
        "coverage": "NODE_ENV=test nyc npm run test",
        "report": "nyc report --reporter=html",
        "report:open": "open ./coverage/index.html",
        "cover": "npm run coverage && npm run report && npm run report:open"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
        "bluebird": "^3.5.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "ava": "^0.22.0",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
        "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
        "nyc": "^11.2.1",
        "sinon": "^3.2.1",
        "testdouble": "^3.2.4"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": ["env"],
        "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
        "env": {
            "test": {
                "plugins": ["istanbul"]
            }
        }
    },
    "ava": {
        "require": ["babel-register"],
        "babel": "inherit"
    },
    "nyc": {
        "sourceMap": false,
        "instrument": false
    }
}
```

Here's whats running:

```
> example@1.0.0 coverage /Users/me/Desktop/example
> NODE_ENV=test nyc npm run test


> example@1.0.0 test /Users/me/Desktop/example
> ava


  11 passed
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|

> example@1.0.0 report /Users/me/Desktop/example
> nyc report --reporter=html


> example@1.0.0 report:open /Users/em/Desktop/example
> open ./coverage/index.html
```

Why isn't `src/index.js` showing in the coverage?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `test.js` under some test folder `test/test.js`